# Using Java AWT components

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, awt

I need to build a userform that requires the use of a Canvas therefore I want to not mix swing components with the AWT ones.

I have gone through quite a few tutorials already and it seems I am missing a key idea that structures the AWT framework.

I am using the GridLayout and GridBagConstraints to set where I want my components. However, resizing and positioning don't seem to work. I want to be able to have 4 rows, the top and the bottom row being quite small in height and going across the entire screen and then to have 4 large squares in a 2x2 grid in the middle of the Form.

```
frame = new Frame("Test Player");   
frame.setSize(800, 800); 
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
```

This should give me the 4x2 grid that I need. Then I want to add a panel to the entire top portion.

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

// Add a panel to the top of the frame
Panel controlPanel = new Panel();
controlPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
controlPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
c.gridx  = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridwidth = 2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
frame.add(controlPanel, c);
```

Why doesn't the setBounds method change the size of my panel?

How can I control the size and position of components in my Form? Is this the right approach for doing this, or am I using the tools wrong?

Comment: GridBagConstraints works with Grid**Bag**Layout, not GridLayout.  They are two entirely different classes.  See their documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was under the assumption that GridBagLayout was a wrapper to help position components within GridLayout.

Comment: Are you adding your controls onto the same `Canvas` been used by `vlcj`?  If you are, it may not work, if you're not, you could try mixing the lightweight components next to the `vlcj` `Canvas`, just avoid trying to add them to each other :P

Answer (score 0):

> I need to build a userform that requires the use of a Canvas

Why?

Use a JPanel and use Swing. You can add components easily to a panel. It has functionality the same as a Canvas, but Swing is more advanced and has better features than AWT. Since you are just learning, spend the time learning Swing.

The [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) has all the Swing basics and is more comprehensive than anything you will find on AWT.

> Why doesn't the setBounds method change the size of my panel?

Why are you trying to use setBounds()?

Swing (and AWT) both use layout managers.

The layout manager will reset the size and location of all the components based on the rules of the layout manager. The size of the panel will then be determined by the components added to the panel.

The tutorial has a section on `How to Use a GridBagLayout` which contains working examples to get you started.

Comment: I need to use Canvas for VLCj library. It's really less than ideal but from what I understand they don't have functionality with Swing yet. So I need to stick with AWT Canvas.

I am trying to understand how to use the LayoutManagers. How can I control the size and location in the Form.

Comment: @JahKnows, I just told you. Use layout managers effectively. Read the tutorial! Download the working examples and play with it and make changes until it does what you want. Note.[Mixing Light and Heavy Weight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) works better now than it did originally so I would try creating a Swing application and just add the Canvas to the content pane of the JFrame.

Comment: I have gone through the examples as the question states. I am having trouble making the tutorials behave the way I want. I feel as though I am missing something. Specifically, this code, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java. How does Form know which grid it's placing the buttons in?

Comment: `How does Form know which grid it's placing the buttons in? ` - I don't understand the question. The tutorial shows you how to do this. What part of the tutorial code do you not understand? Be specific with your questions. You specify the gridx/y values. If you have a problem then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You can't just randomly create a 4x2 grid. You actually need to have 8 components to add to each cell of the grid.

Comment: `I want to be able to have 4 rows, the top and the bottom row being quite small in height and going across the entire screen and then to have 4 large squares in a 2x2 grid in the middle of the Form` - create a panel and add it to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START, Add another panel  to BorderLayout.CENTER. Add a third panel  to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END. Each panel can use a different layout manager. You might consider this a typical layout of a frame where you have a "toolbar", "application content", "status bar".

Comment: If I do exactly what you suggested. Which is what I am doing. All the panels have the exact same size. And if I use the setSize options it doesn't change. That is the essence of my question. I didn't include all my code or trials to make it more readable hoping that someone with experience could understand that I am unfamiliar with the details of front-end development.

Comment: @JahKnows, If you have one row of components in the top panel and two rows of components in the center panel than they won't be the same size. So if they are the same size you are doing something wrong. `I didn't include all my code`  - we are not interested in your application code. We are interested in an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in a simple way. Each Swing component is responsible for determining its own size. If you are doing custom painting or something like that, then you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class so the layout manager can do its job.